# SSIS file move and rename

Tags: sql-server, ssis

As part of migration from traditional system to new technology, I need to rename N number of files[.txt, .pdf, .xl, etc] available in the particular folder using SSIS.

1. Move the file to destination
2. Parse the prefix of files which is used as ID for associating with the record in the table.
   Ex: 1012BA12_Attach_Emp.doc   [ID=1012BA12]
3. Then I need to go to database and lookup the new ID.
   Ex: old ID=1012BA12 and equivalent new ID=512
4. Then replace the old ID with new one.
   Ex: 512_Attach_Emp.doc
5. Insert one row to some table with respect new name & path.

I have been used the for each file enumerator, Execute sqltask and file system task
but it's consuming a day to do so.

Please guide me best approach.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does "consuming a day to do so" mean that the package takes a day to run? The solution you described seems quite normal, so you need to give more details about what isn't working. If your problem is that it's running slowly, how many files are you processing and have you checked the package logs to see where the time is being used? Have you tried using the Script task or an external program/script to do some of the processing?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is likely to be on the database side, not SSIS. 
Do you have indexes on the tables you are accessing?
Are the files local to the SSIS instance, or does SSIS access the files remotely?

Comment: No. Database response not impacting. This is because of remote machine bandwidth. Hence while I renaming file over the remote machine it is taking too much time. I resolved this with some C# console app. I'm executing this console app in the remote machine itself.